# Como mostrar motivo do erro 422 em GO

Tags: golang

Ultimamente estou quebrando muito a cabeça para debugar a requisições POST e PUT onde sempre ocorre o erro HTTP 422 (Formato de entrada incorreto)

Em meu projeto eu estou utilizando o framework GIN para fazer um BIND do JSON enviado pelo front-end. Precisava saber qual é o atributo da estrutura que não está no formato adequado.

Como faço para dar um PRINT dos erros de validação?

Tentei o seguinte:

```
func postPerson(c *gin.Context) {

    var person models.Person
    c.BindJSON(&person)

    fmt.Print(c.Errors.Error())
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que para mostrar os erros seja 400 ou 422 é possível pegar do BindJSON. Ficaria mais o menos assim:

```
func postPerson(c *gin.Context) {

    var person models.Person
    err := c.BindJSON(&person)

    if err != nil {
       fmt.Print(err.Error())
    }
}
```